# How to start strapi-docker with pm2?

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2, strapi

Is there any way to start [strapi/strapi](https://hub.docker.com/r/strapi/strapi) docker images with pm2? Since the default command for [strapi/strapi](https://hub.docker.com/r/strapi/strapi) docker images is strapi develop.

Answer (score 1):

PM2 is already included in the Docker image

Use docker-compose to start your project then you will be able to get inside your guest os image and run commands.

`sudo docker exec -it strapi bash`
create `ecosystem.config.js` file

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

[Please check this blog post.](https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-run-a-strapi-dev-stack-with-docker-compose)

Comment: sorry, strapi/strapi docker images doesn't include file ecosystem.config.js

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way to do this is install strapi using cli, then ship it to docker using strapi/base docker image and add pm2 in the Dockerfile.

```
FROM strapi/base

WORKDIR /srv/app

COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./

RUN npm install pm2 -g

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["pm2-runtime", "server.js"]
```